# shell scripting: how to test the existence of a single file

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to test the existence of .doc files in particular directory.

```
    if [ ! -f /home/ankur/*.doc ]
    then echo "no doc files exist."
    else echo "files exist"
    fi
```

Now if no doc file or single doc file exists, it works fine.
but if there are multiple doc file, still it is working but throwing kind of warning "too many arguments".
So how can I test the existence of multiple doc files. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only looking weather file exist or not, then I guess you should avoid that hassle:

You can simply do

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -l /home/ankur/*.doc &>/dev/null
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "no doc files exist."
else
  echo "files exist"
fi
```

One can also reduce one statement by using following `if`

```
 if ls home/ankur/*.doc &>/dev/null; then
   echo "files exist"
 else
   echo "no doc files exist."
 fi
```

Why to awake arrays from their sleep, if you don't want to do anything specific with them :)

Comment: thnx for the reply...first line ls -l /home/ankur/*.doc 1>&- 2>&- throwing the error with status 2.
eankuls@L9AHR43:~/ankur$ echo $?
2
I have the .doc file in my dir. but its reflecting "no doc files exist" could you pls help as I am not much aware of this &- thing..thnx

Comment: changed it to more familiar one `&>/dev/null` . seems previous one changing the exist status.

Answer (score 2):

In your comments, you expand on your original question to say:

> What I want is, that it checks for the files and at last produces a single result. If no doc file is there then "no doc files exist" or if one or more files are there then "doc files exist"

A lot depends on your shell. With Bash, you can use a counter to determine whether you have found *any* matching files. For example:

```
files=(/home/ankur/*.doc)
files_found=0

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    [[ -f "$file" ]] && files_found+=1
done

if [[ $files_found == 0 ]]; then
    echo "no doc files exist"
else
    echo "files exist"
fi
```

The key is to use an array to store the filenames, and the loop through the test one filename at a time. The *files_found* variable is then checked to see if you have any matches at all. It Works for Me™.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I am using bash on my ubuntu machine. Your code is also working for me but problem is, for every file it is printing exists or doesn't exist.
What I want is, that it checks for the files and at last produces a single result. 
If no doc file is there then "no doc files exist" or if one or more files are there then "doc files exist"...thanks

Comment: @user2611539: then don't echo inside the loop. Instead set a flag to false before the loop and set it to true if any of the files exist. Then echo _after_ the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
shopt -s nullglob          # if a glob pattern matches no files, 
                           # do NOT return the pattern as a plain string,

files=( /path/to/*.doc )

if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then
    echo "no doc files there"
fi
```

Comment: This is Bash-only, though.